# Word Add-in object always null

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins, cpu-word, imanage

I'm trying to get iManage Word Add-in object using the following code

```
using Com.iManage.WorkSiteAddinInterfaces;

public void ManageIManageWordAddIn()
{
    iManageExtensibility iManageAddinObj = null;

    (COMAddIn addin in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.COMAddIns)
    {   
        string iManage2007orLater = "WorkSiteOffice2007Addins.Connect"

                if (addin.ProgId.Contains(iManage2007orLater))
                {
                    // If addin is connected, try to hijack the DocumentClose2 event
                    if (addin.Connect)
                    {
                        iManageAddinObj = addin.Object as iManageExtensibility; //addin.Object is null
                        // register to iManageAddinObj events here
                        iManageAddinObj.DocumentBeforeClose2 += IManageAddinObj_DocumentBeforeClose2;
                    }
                }
          }
}

private void IManageAddinObj_DocumentBeforeClose2(object Doc, ref bool IgnoreIManageClose, ref bool Cancel)
{
    IgnoreIManageClose = true;
    Cancel = true;
}
```

The add-in is connected but the addin.Object always returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COMAddin.Object` property is not the COM object that implements `IDTExtensibility2` etc interface. The addin can potentially expose *some* object that it explicitly *wants* to expose. If not, it will be null.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I cannot use this approach.